# AWS Cloudformation: How to use username as a tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I need to create a Cloudformation Script for an ec2 instance which should have tags specifying among other things, the aws username of the person who ran the script to create the instance. What is the variable name to get the IAM Username? The tagging part of my script is shown below. Whereas the AccountId can be retrieved, I'm unable to get the username.

```
    Tags:
    - Key: Name
      Value: !Ref InstanceName
    - Key: team
      Value: !Ref Team
    - Key: awsAccount
      Value: !Sub ${AWS::AccountId}
    - Key: userName
      Value: !Sub ${AWS::IAM::User}
    - Key: purpose
      Value: !Ref Purpose
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately **there is no such pseudo parameter** in CloudFormation. The list of all available parameters, such as `AWS::AccountId` is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html).

One way around this is to create a **parameter** for your CloudFormation template (as you do with `Purpose` or `team`), e.g.

```
Parameters:
    UserName:
      Type: String
```

and reference it in your `Tags`:

```
- Key: userName
  Value: !Ref UserName
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I have already been using the method you suggested. Just wanted to have a more foolproof method so team members don't put someone else's name when using the script.

Comment: @RameshMenon Maybe you could look at Service Catalog if you want to have more control over tags. But it can't be done from plain CloudFormation. I feel your pain. Tagging is complex, and usually requires discipline and education of your team members.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Service Catalog. The `aws:servicecatalog:provisioningPrincipalArn` auto tag will be added to all provisioned resources.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/latest/adminguide/autotags.html